# CURL chunked POST from infinite pipe?

Tags: http, curl, post, pipe, chunked

I want to continuously post an infinite binary data stream to a webserver.
So I'm using the following command:

```
curl -X POST -H "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" -d 'hello' http://127.0.0.1:9000
```

As a test, I'm piping the output of the 'yes' command:

```
$ yes | curl -X POST -H "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" -d '@-' http://127.0.0.1:9000
```

But it doesn't even connect to the webserver, and aborts with an out-of-memory error. It seems curl is trying to read the whole file into memory before starting the transfer.

Does curl supports continuously HTTP posting data coming from a pipe? (I'm using curl version 7.61.0).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
yes | curl -T. http://127.0.0.1:9000
```

But you will probably get this known bug :

- https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/2051
- https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/932

Or

```
yes | curl -T- http://127.0.0.1:9000
```

Comment: I assume you meant "curl -T." ? Could you please check and correct?